# Propositional logic : commas and implication confusion

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

Im trying to transalate this sentence into propositional logic:

> The square of a nonzero integer is positive.

The solution of my book states the following:
$$   
    \forall x \in \mathbf{Z}, (x \neq 0) \implies ( x^2 > 0)
    $$

However i did this:

$$   
    (\forall x \in \mathbf{Z} \land x \neq 0 ) ( x^2 > 0)
    $$
The reason why i didn't use implication was because in the same book for this sentence:

> For all natural numbers n, $n^2 + n + 41$ is prime.

The book translates it like this

$$(\forall n \in N)(n^2 + n + 41 \text{ is prime}) $$

and the implication was not used which left me confused

My question is:

> When is necessary to use an implication , and  it is correct to use an
> "and" rather than a comma?

Comment: Try to look for the assumption and conclusion. In the example you mention, the assumption is "positive integer" whereas the conclusion is "the square of that number is strictly greater than zero". What kind of logical relation is the most suitable in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps $(\forall x \in \mathbb Z \land x \neq 0 ) ( x^2 > 0) $ may sound intuitive to you, but is not the correct way to convey what you want. You want every integer that is not $0$  to have a positive square. The way you wrote it is syntactically incorrect (rigurously, it is ambiguous) , but even if it was written as $\forall x \in \mathbb Z  (x \neq 0  \land x^2 > 0) $, it would say that every integer is not $0$ AND has a positive square, both of these assertions are false. You want the integers which are not $0$, to have a positive square, so in this case, in order to "check" if some $x \in \mathbb Z$ has a positive square, you first need to "check" if said $x$ is not $0$, hence  $\forall x \in \mathbb Z ( x \neq 0 \Rightarrow x^2 > 0)$ . As for the latter proposition abount $n^2 + n +41$, there is nothing to check *a priori*, since the wording of the sentence simply states "for all natural numbers". This last statement is actually false by the way.

Answer (score 0):

> The square of a nonzero integer is positive.

The correct form for your attempt would be: $$\forall x~.((x\in\Bbb Z\wedge x\neq 0)\to(x^2>0))$$

> and the implication was not used which left me confused

Universal statements with forms like $\forall x~. (x\in\mathcal S\to \varphi(x))$ may be shortened by abbreviating the *set inclusion* with the declaration of the bound variable — to $\forall x\in\mathcal S~.\varphi(x)$ —, but this is *only* allowed for set inclusions.

So, since $\Bbb Z{\smallsetminus}\{0\}$ is the *set* of non-zero integers, you *might* represent the statement as: $$\forall x\in \Bbb Z{\smallsetminus}\{0\} ~. x^2>0 $$

Alternatively you may notice that, by the exportation equivalence, your attempt may also be written as: $$\forall x~. (x\in\Bbb Z\to(x\neq 0\to x^2>0))$$

Thus this may be abbreviated to the answer's form:$$\forall x\in\Bbb Z~.(x\neq 0\to x^2>0) $$

Or with bracketing around the variable binding instead of the punctuation. $$(\forall x\in\Bbb Z)~(x\neq 0\to x^2>0)$$